# Correct Way to Use $_POST

Tags: php, session, session-variables

If I have three PHP pages, lets call them one.php, two.php, and three.php, and I use something like this on the first page:

```
<form name = "one" action = "two.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method ="post">
```

I understand that I can now use the variables I passed alone from one.php in two.php...

My question is, how would I use the variables from one.php in three.php?

I keep getting "undefined index" errors every time I try to call them as I would in two.php.

Thank you very much for your help!

Edit: I should have mentioned that I am using Sessions as well.

On the second page, I do something like this:

> $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];

and it lets me pass on the name gathered from that first page to the second one, but when I attempt to do this on the third page, it just says "undefined index".

Comment: How do you call three.php, GET? POST? include inside two.php?

Comment: Sessions maybe could help. to share data between pages.

Comment: @Somy A - I should have mentioned that, I am using sessions.

Comment: if you want to access the variable in your 3.php just put require_once("2.php") .. at the start of the line... any variable is accessible in other file if its included in the next file..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using post, you would need to use $_SESSION

so for example:

one.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["mypostvalue"] = $_POST["mypostvalue"];
$_SESSION["mypostvalue1"] = $_POST["mypostvalue1"];
```

three.php

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["mypostvalue"];
echo "<br />";
echo $_SESSION["mypostvalue1"];
```

Then once you are done with the session data, you need to get rid of it like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = null;
session_destory();
```

**Note** Only use session_start() once per page, and before any data is sent to the browser such as html or white space.

Comment: Hmmh, I should mention that the third page is using an included class and the class is what actually needs the variable. But echoing the session in the class does nothing. Any tips for that?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that I can now use the variables I passed alone from one.php in two.php...

Not as such.

Successful form controls in the form will submit their values to `two.php`. You can then access them via `$_POST['name_of_control']`.

If you generate form controls (possibly of type hidden) with values created from PHP variables (making sure to escape them to defend against XSS attacks) then they will appear in the form and be submitted.

> My question is, how would I use the variables from one.php in three.php?

That depends on how the browser gets to three.php. You could generate another form and put the values in hidden inputs again.

Comment: Thank you. I was going to add something about security.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is per request You should pass them to the third file using $_SESSION or $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your input elements are named correctly.  If you want to use `$_POST["myvar"]` in *two.php*, then the `name` attribute in *one.php* needs to be "myvar".

```
<form action="two.php" method="post">
    <input type='text' value='test myvar' name='myvar' />
    <input type='submit' value='go to 2' />
</form>
```

---

To use the variables from *one.php* in *three.php*, just pass them through as hidden inputs.  That is, echo them back to the form in *two.php*:

```
<form action="three.php" method="post">
    <input type='text' value='test var 2' name='myvar2' />

    <?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='myvar' value='" . $_POST["myvar"] . "' />"; ?>

    <input type='submit' value='go to 3' />
</form>
```